# Mode selection inside Tkinter mainloop()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

I am having the following problem:
I want to be able to select a mode while one of the three if statements is running and when is finishes to go to the one that is selected. For excample if 'mode' is running and I select 'p' after the 's' if ends the 'p' if starts. 
I also want this processes to run unstopably
Thank you :D

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

answer = ''

root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x150')
root.title('Mode Selection')

v = tk.IntVar()
v.set(0)  # initializing the choice, i.e. Python
b1 = Button()

modes = [
    ('s', 'to start"'),
    ('p', 'to pause'),
    ('a', 'to abort'),
]

tk.Label(root,
         text="""Choose a mode:""",
         justify=tk.CENTER,
         padx=20).pack()

for val, language in enumerate(modes):
    tk.Radiobutton(root,
                   text=language,
                   padx=20,
                   variable=v,
                   value=val,
                   justify=tk.CENTER).pack()

answer = modes[v.get()][0]

if answer == 's':
    print('s')
    # do something...
elif answer == 'p':
    print('p')
    # do something...
elif answer == 'a':
    print('a')
    # do something...

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should use the `command` option to associate a callback and put the if blocks logic inside the callback instead.

Comment: You should probably read up on GUI toolkits and the event-driven programming model that they use.

Answer (score 0):

Here, using `command`, we can associate an event or Function triggered by the selection of the radio button

```
modes = [
    ('s', 'to start"'),
    ('p', 'to pause'),
    ('a', 'to abort'),
]


def show_mode(z):
    # Do something...
    print(z)


tk.Radiobutton(root,
               text=modes[0],
               padx=20,
               variable=v,
               value=0,
               justify=tk.CENTER,
               command = lambda : show_mode('s')).pack()

tk.Radiobutton(root,
               text=modes[1],
               padx=20,
               variable=v,
               value=1,
               justify=tk.CENTER,
               command = lambda : show_mode('p')).pack()

tk.Radiobutton(root,
               text=modes[2],
               padx=20,
               variable=v,
               value=2,
               justify=tk.CENTER,
               command = lambda : show_mode('a')).pack()
```

Hope this helps :)